# Use model classes or setter properties with MVP

Tags: c#, .net, mvp

I'm creating my application using setter properties, like

```
public interface IUserRegistrationView
{
    string DisplayName { set; }
    string EmailAddress { set; }
}
```

But I'm not sure if this is a good way to do...

Maybe I should create a Model property on the Presenter class?

What do you suggest?

thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing will get the job done, but the set-only properties are a smell. Your setters, without getters, are essentially *methods* disguised as properties, which *works* but doesn't make much *sense*.

**First**, since the view has no reason what so ever of knowing anything at all about the presenter, there's no reason for it to create the presenter and inject itself to it. Instead, create the concrete view at a composition root, then the concrete presenter with the view constructor-injected into it. The presenter can then listen to events defined in the view interface so that presenter and view are as loosely coupled as possible.

**Second**, I would change the setter *properties* to `SetDisplayName` and `SetEmailAddress` methods, but only if the view can be updated by the presenter after shown and not just displaying static data. Otherwise I'd remove them completely. Remember that likely [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAGNI/%20YAGNI).

**Third**, my primary way of conveying the initial data to display in the view would be like this, through the view's `Show` method:

```
public class UserRegistrationInfo
{
    string DisplayName { get; set; }
    string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}

public interface IUserRegistrationView
{
    void SetDisplayName(string name);
    void SetEmailAddress(string name);

    // ... events for the presenter to hook into.

    void Show(UserRegistrationInfo info);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use this interface as in general way and others classes can use this then its better way to do.If you are specifically going to create interface then it's not a good way make property in presenter class.
As per this IUserRegistrationView i would suggest make these properties in your Business logic layer and set those properties from presenter layer .

Comment: it's probably the way I'm doing now, the presentation layer will be an asp.net web app or mvc, not sure yet. I'll implement that interface on the webcontrol...

Comment: If you are going to implement on web control then make it is business layer properties. That would be great